# How do you say “I had hoped I’d be able to get something to translate out of this!”

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Where *this* is a forum post and the tone is one in which I did, indeed, get something to translate out of the post (exclamation with an elative tone, I suppose).   I did try a dictionary and googling but turned up nothing.  It’s a quite specific question, I think …

I did think of the possibility:

> Ich habe gehofft, dass ich etwas zu übersetzen aus diesem Beitrag holen können würde.

But that seems wrong to me.  Or if not wrong, not very idiomatic.

Comment: Your suggestion is almost correct. "zu übersetzen" should be replaced by the nominalization "zum Übersetzen" which sounds more natural to a native speaker. I'm not completely sure why, probably because vocal collision is avoided. Furthermore, expressions like "holen können würde" (more than two verbs in a row) should be avoided whenever it's possible. "holen könnte" is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

- Ich hatte gehofft, dass ich etwas zum Übersetzen aus diesem Post herausholen kann/könnte.
- Ich hatte gehofft, dass dieser Post etwas zum Übersetzen hergibt.
- Ich hatte mir von/in diesem Post etwas zum Übersetzen erhofft.

The third option is the most formal one, the others are rather colloquial.

However, *ich hatte gehofft* does not indicate whether your hopes came true. If you want to clarify that, you can start your sentence as follows:

- Ich bin froh, dass … *(I’m glad …)*
- Ich wusste, dass … *(I knew …)*
- Schön, dass … *(Nice to see that …)*

or

- Schade. Ich hatte [eigentlich] gehofft, dass … *(Pity! I was hoping that …)*